# Nivo Slider is slightly changing size when image changes, how to solve this?

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I have set Nivo Slider using the code provided, I have not changed the code at all.
The 4 images I use are the exact same size (not the same resolution though).

When the images slide, they move the entire website up and then down a little.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Well. Some of your html structure would be nice to see

Comment: Please add your code for us to see, even if it is the provided code.

Comment: probaly has something to do with the position of the div where the slider is placed in